# Anthology book including a short story about a vampire living in a big city, who falls in love with a cat

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

The book in question contained several short stories by different authors. The title was something to the effects of *The Shades of Gray*, or *The Gray of Depression*, or *The Shades of Depression*, or something with those words.

The only story I can remember being in the book was focused on a vampire in a big city. He lives in a crappy shack where a cat eventually takes residence. He apprehensively falls in love with the feline and ends up having to take it to get help when it's sick. The story ending with the vampire taking it to a church-based vet clinic and possibly dying.

I read this book back in middle school between 2005 and 2010 if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: There was a 2006 anthology titled [*Shades of Grey*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?274953) but it only contains stories by two different authors, the brothers Jeffrey Grey and Scott Grey. Does the cover or any of the story titles look familiar?

Comment: [Shades of Darkness](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6218528-shades-of-darkness)? I cannot find a copy online but you might recognise the cover.